# What does typedef int var[1]; do?

Tags: c++, typedef

I've encountered the following code:

```
typedef int var[1]; // or var[3]
```

what does it actually do? I don't understand what does the subscript add, since now I can define "var" for int

Comment: I think this defines that `var test` would declare an int array with the array size of 1

Comment: Please don't use typedef like this.

Comment: @Rapptz: That is actually quite common in metaprogramming to have types of *known to differ* sizes: `typedef char yes; typedef char (&no)[2];` then create two overloads that return `yes` and `no`, and test which is selected with `sizeof( f(...) ) == sizeof(yes)` --this depends only on `sizeof(yes)!=sizeof(no)`

Comment: Incidentally, `var` is a bad name for a type. The name implies that `var` is a variable rather than a type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`var` is a type definition for an `int` array of size one.

You can write

```
var x;
```

and `x` will be a variable of type `int[1]`

Comment: so it's the same as
typedef int[3] var;
?

Comment: @lezebulon no. `typedef int[3] var;` is illegal.

Comment: x is variable of type int[1] in this case.

Comment: Note that `var x;` cannot be written anywhere, it must be written in specific locations. You may want to clarify that, a beginner might get confused.

Comment: @GManNickG sure it can. But probably won't compile in some places... Honestly now, what's the big deal? `var` is a type.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: Right, as written you've specified that it can be written, but failed to specify where. A beginner might get confused. (Do you see how annoying this pedantry is?)

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: Still not correct: `typedef int var[1]; int main() var {}`.

Comment: @GManNickG aite', feel free to downvote or answer yourself. ;)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15780/discussion-between-gmannickg-and-luchian-grigore)

Comment: @GManNickG: `var x;` is a variable declaration. *Of course* it can only be written in certain places. I fail to see why that's worth mentioning in this answer.

Comment: @KeithThompson: I was being sarcastic, because apparently such "of course" things must be written out, according to Luchian.

Comment: @GManNickG: Sarcasm isn't always obvious in print. I presume you were referring to your deleted answer, which I wasn't able to comment on. You wrote "`var` is an array of a single `int`.". The problem with that is that when I see "`var` is an array ...", it tells me that `var` is an *object*, not a *type*. Consider that your statement would have been clear and correct given the declaration `int var[1];`. Luchian's comment was not pedantry; he was pointing out that your answer was unclear. If you had written "array type" rather than "array", there would have been no problem.

Comment: @GManNickG: I can understand that "`var` is an array" might not imply *to you* that `var` is an object, but you should be aware that many, probably most, other people would read it that way.

Comment: An important point about `typedef`: despite the name, a `typedef` does *not* define a new type. Instead, it defines a new name for an existing type. Given `typedef int var[1];`, `var` and `int[1]` are not different types, they're different names for the same type.

Comment: @KeithThompson: `var` is in reference to the `var` in the question. If I walked up to you in a hallway and said, in speech, "`var is an array of five ints", I wouldn't doubt you'd think of an object. This isn't a hallway and we aren't missing context. It's already established we're talking about a type. Anyway, this is stupid to me and don't quite care enough to address it further, and it's just noise, so that'll be that from me

Comment: @GManNickG: The fact that it's a type is hardly obvious to someone like the OP *who's effectively asking what `typedef` means*. Really, if a lot of people told me I had written something unclear, I'd seriously consider the possibility that I had written something unclear.

Answer (score 8):

`typedef` declarations use the same syntax as ordinary variable declarations.  The difference is that instead of declaring "a variable named `x` of type `y`," you declare "a type named `x` that is a synonym for type `y`."  The syntax is otherwise the same.

So, let's remove the `typedef` from your example and see what we get:

```
int var[1];
```

`var` is a variable whose type is `int[1]`, or, an array of one `int`.  If we add the `typedef` back:

```
typedef int var[1];
```

this makes `var` a synonym for the type `int[1]`.

The same works for other kinds of ugly or complex types:

```
int (*fp)(int);         // fp is a function pointer variable
typedef int (*fp)(int); // fp is a function pointer type
```

---

You can avoid most of this confusion by using an `identity` template, declared as

```
template <typename T> struct identity { typedef T type; };
```

Using this template, the meaning of a complex type or variable declaration is much clearer.  For example, we can declare our types like so:

```
typedef identity<int[1]     >::type var; // array type
typedef identity<int(*)(int)>::type fp;  // function pointer type
```

and because variable declarations use the same syntax as type declarations, we can declare variables that have a complex using `identity` as well:

```
identity<int[1]     >::type var; // array variable
identity<int(*)(int)>::type fp;  // function pointer variable
```